# convert MySQL date result to monthname and create variables

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL database with a date column.

I create a variable of the value in PHP like this:

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT customer_date FROM customers WHERE customer_id = {$_SESSION['session_id']}");

while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    $date = $result->customer_date;
}
```

I need to convert the `$date`from YYYY-MM-DD to three variables

- `$yearvalue` (for example **2012**)
- `$monthname` (for example **August**)
- `$dayvalue` (for example **10**)

And I need to be able to echo out anywhere in my code... How would I do this in a fancy way? I'm pretty new to coding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
  $date = $result->customer_date;
  $yearvalue = date("Y", strtotime($date) );
  $monthname = date("F", strtotime($date) );
  $dayvalue = date("d", strtotime($date) );
}
```

It'll only work/store the value of these values for the last row outputted from the `$result`.

Comment: @David : If it worked like a charm then would you mind [accepting answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? This is how SO works.

Comment: Yes, but I had to wait for 8 minutes before I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    $date = $result->customer_date;
    list($year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute,$second)=
    explode('-',date('Y-F-d-h-i-s',strtotime($date)));
}
```

***Also read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). You will need to play with `Y-F-d-h-i-s` as per your requirement.***

Comment: `Year`, `month` (full month, ie. August)  and `day`.

Comment: @FahimParkar it'll be `date('Y-F-d'...`

Comment: @Nerd-Herd : Thanks for catch,,, Edited the same.. OP will need to play with that...

Comment: @FahimParkar Sorry. I am talking about waht Nerd-Herd commented. Need to be `date('Y-f-d');`, but you already edited (so, you get what I am talking).

Comment: @GabrielSantos : Now it is clear. I have added more so that OP can get more. Value added service is good idea in marketing...